# ¿Debemos aceptar siempre una edición sugerida por una cuenta duplicada a la del autor de una publicación?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas, reportes, cuentas-de-usuario

Vi el otro día la pregunta [Bash script compra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/363437/83). Bastante pobre de redacción, consulté para saber más detalles y al rato vi que había [una sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/216790). No era una gran edición, pero era del mismo usuario. ¿Por qué entró entonces en la cola de revisión? Pues porque [el usuario original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/177331/narnia) por algún motivo luego [registró una cuenta con el mismo nombre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/177335/narnia) e hizo la edición.

Di a aceptar a la revisión, pero los dos siguientes la rechazaron. Al verlo, lo reporté a los moderadores:

> se rechazó una sugerencia de edición que hizo el mismo usuario (con otra cuenta), ¿podría recuperarse?

El reporte se me ha rechazado con este motivo:

> no agrega nada a la pregunta, y como si fuera poco, despues no se va a poder aceptar la respuesta

Al verlo, añadí un comentario al usuario indicando que:

> Narnia: parece que tienes múltiples cuentas (según la edición [es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/216790](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/216790)). Sugiero mirar [He creado dos cuentas accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo combinarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Pues si junta las cuentas, el usuario registrado tendrá la *propiedad* de la pregunta y, por tanto, podrá aceptarla.

Sé que esta parte de juntar cuentas puede explicársela cualquier usuario, pero me sorprende que el moderador encargado deje pasar la situación rechazando revisitar la sugerencia de edición. No creo que se haya hecho lo suficiente para mejorar la experiencia de este usuario.

Dudas:

- Por pobre que sea, si es una edición del mismo autor de la pregunta, ¿no correspondería aceptarla?
- ¿Los moderadores realmente deben dejar pasar tales situaciones sin más?
- ¿Podrían detallar las moderadores si hay algún criterio que manejen y que se me esté escapando?

Todo ello dando por sentado que la pregunta es mala, faltan detalles y el usuario probablemente no vuelva. Pero lo mismo hay casos parecidos que valdría la pena manejar con más empatía.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo lo rechace...

Y me hago cargo de no haberle puesto al usuario el mensaje cuando tiene cuentas duplicadas.. Pido disculpas a todos por eso... se me paso.

Pero lo otro, si acepto una edición de otro usuario, no le enseñamos al usuario que debe tener una sola cuenta, porque le rescatamos todos los errores. Por lo menos, segun mi punto de vista...

Pero si, estuve mal en no ponerle inmediatemente al usuario el aviso que pidiera unificar sus cuentas.

Y vuelvo a pedir disculpas

Comment: ¡Gracias Gonzalo! Muy agradecido de las explicaciones. No hay porqué disculparse, gracias por la transparencia y la rapidez explicándote.